# How can I make zabbix respond to emails?

Tags: linux, email, zabbix

I have not been able to find much information on how I could respond to email alerts from the Zabbix server.

So far I have a local instance of an Email server set up for testing out email alerts. My first approach would be to send the problem ID in the email alert, and then parsing it on the email server and pushing it as an Item (probably). I would do this php on the Zabbix server using the Zabbix API. It seems a bit messy but not so far fetched.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why would you respond to an alert (by mail)?

Comment: I want to be able to launch scripts based on the problems that are coming by responding to an email with a keyword, or acknowledge or close problems.